# Layout bug in User Profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-profiles

There is a small layout bug in the User Profile page for the reputation and responses tab.

The `graph` link for the reputation section and the `all` link on the responses section is cut off.

**Reputation Tab**
[image: Reputation tab - Graph link cut off]

**Responses Tab**
[image: Responses tab - All link cut off]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.